# Add json value into state using useState

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, use-state

I was trying to push json object into excesting useState. While I console.log it and  i got my default data perfectly. while i try to push new data over old data. My new data was not push.

```
const [shopCart, setShopCart] = useState({Description:"Apple"});

 const disptechProductUpdate = (prod: any) => {

        console.log(prod)

        let updatedValue = {};
        updatedValue = prod;

        console.log(updatedValue)
        
        setShopCart(shopCart => ({
             ...shopCart,
             ...updatedValue
           }));

console.log(shopCart)
    }

<Button  onChange={(e) => disptechProductUpdate({ Description: "Fruits" })}>Print</Button>
```

Console output was

```
{Description: 'Fruits'}
{Description: 'Fruits'}
{Description: 'Apple'}
```

Comment: are you sure it is not updated? You should log in `useEffect` hook, because `setShopCart` is async. Example:
`useEffect(() => console.log(shopCart), [shopCart])`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
setShopCart(shopCart => ({
  ...shopCart,
  ...updatedValue
}));
```

with

```
setShopCart({
  ...shopCart,
  ...updatedValue
});
```

( you were replacing your object with a function that returns an object instead of replacing it with the new object )